# Increasing vibration intensity in pixel XL

Tags: vibration, google-pixel

I can barely feel the vibration in my pixel XL. Is there any way to increase it? Some posts suggest there should be a "Sound and Vibration" setting but my O does not have one.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Android does not provide a stock setting that will control global vibration intensity because not all phone hardware supports the ability to control vibration amplitude.

Instead, Android has released updates to the `Vibrator` control as of Android API level 26 (aka: Android Oreo).

Developers can check if the hardware supports adjusting haptic feedback intensity by calling `Vibrator#hasAmplitudeControl`.

If so, they can create their own haptic feedback by calling `Vibrator#vibrate` and passing in a desired `VibrationEffect`, which is the object definition of a vibration pattern, including amplitude.

In summary, vibration control is up to the phone hardware capabilities and developers now as of Android Oreo.

---

**Note:** there may be third party apps on the Play Store that allow for more fine grained or global vibration control, but I am unsure which is viable and whether or not root permissions are required - so YMMV.